# Remove BuildType debug from uploadArchives task in Gradle

Tags: maven, android-gradle-plugin

I have a build.gradle file to build and upload on a private Maven Repository an Android library (.aar) Script is perfectly working, but the problem, it uploads my two buildType on the maven repo (debug and release builds) and I would like to upload only the release one.

Here my script:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    // Generate Jar of the Javadoc
    task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: generateReleaseJavadoc) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from generateReleaseJavadoc.destinationDir
    }

    // Include Javadoc Jar file in the Maven repository
    artifacts {
        archives androidJavadocsJar
    }

    // Task to upload SDK in Maven private repository
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: "***") {
                    authentication(userName: '***', password: '***')
                }
                snapshotRepository(url: "***") {
                    authentication(userName: '***', password: '***')
                }
                pom.project {
                    artifactId '***'
                    name '***'
                    packaging 'aar'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that it is possible by writting this defaultPublishConfig "release" in the android {} part, but when I do that, I cannot use my library in a debug build for debugging. I did not find any workaround to stop uploading the debug package than to comment and uncomment depending on what I would like to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it the following way and I get only release artifacts in the packaged AAR.

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

uploadArchives {
    configuration = configurations.archives

    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: 'http://myserver/artifactory/libs-release-local') {
                authentication(userName: artifactoryUsername, password: artifactoryPassword)
            }

            snapshotRepository(url: 'http://myserver/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local') {
                authentication(userName: artifactoryUsername, password: artifactoryPassword)
            }

            pom.project {
                name 'somelibrary'
                description 'some library'

                scm {
                    developerConnection 'repo location'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the contrary, I was actually looking for a way to publish separate artifact for debug and release but couldn't find heh :)

Comment: I don't see where you specify that you only want release

Answer (score 3):

[this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-does-uploadarchives-task-upload/12922/2) might help to resolve your issue. Basically it uses the release build by default. However, it seems you can override the behaviour by;

```
android {
    defaultPublishConfig "flavor1Debug"
}
```

Comment: I would like to have both (debug and release) in Maven and download both.

Comment: I don't know how many 'flavors' you have but if you only have 'debug' and 'release', you can try setting 'publishNonDefault true' and running the task again.